# short way to store input variables in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all: Yes I know, this is not what you call elegant programming, but my only target is to do it short, not readable.

Now the real problem:
I want to store an amount of x Strings in a list.
The user inputs how many Strings he wants to input and then one by one afterwards. Here's what I got so far:

```
print(
    [
        exec(
            ('input("text: "),' * int(input('number: ')))[:-1]
        )
    ]
)
```

And this is a sample output:

```
number: 4
text: one
text: two
text: three
text: four
[None]
```

Why arent the inputs taken into account during list creation?
And how can i do this (short[er])?

Comment: `print([input('text: ') for i in range(int(input('number: ')))])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest and dumbest I could produce...

```
 print map(input,['text: ']*input("number: "))
```

- `input("number: ")` produce an `str` given the user input
- `['text: ']*input` produce an array of length equal to the input, containing `'text: '` for every values
- `map` iterate over the array and give the value to `input`
- results are return as a list and printed

Edit Python3:

```
 print(list(map(input,['text: ']*int(input("number: ")))))
```

Edit2: Saved one char for python2 thx to @Delgan

Comment: Nice. You can also remove `print()` parenthesis and save one char for Python 2.

Comment: Thx, I feel like this question could have been put in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ... Also it's not much of a challenge

Answer (score 3):

Shorter **and** more readable.

```
print([input("text: ") for i in range(int(input("number: ")))])
```

Comment: I upvote as this is exactly what I was about to post ... :D

Comment: You could also remove `int()` cast and save 5 char as OP seems to love dirty short things

Comment: @Cyrbil I can not as OP is using Python 3. However, he may use `[0]*int(input("number: "))` instead of `range(int(input("number: ")))` which saves 3 chars.

Answer (score 1):

Readable > short almost every time.

In this instance, assuming you want a list of strings from the user, something like:

```
count = int(input("number of strings: "))
strings = []
for i in range(count):
    strings.append(input("text: "))
print(strings)
```

should work.

In general, try to avoid `exec`.

Comment: yeah I know that, but actually it's for http://www.spoj.com/SHORTEN/ one of the rare places where short > readable